# Differentiate the following equation

Tags: calculus

We know that $ \int  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1-x^2}} dx = \arcsin(x) + c $

Use this information to find $ f(x) $ below

$$ \int f(x) \,dx = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{ 1-x^2}} + c$$

Comment: Your top equation is incorrect.

Comment: Do you mean $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\arcsin x+c?$

Comment: Observe
$$\int{\dfrac{1}{1-x^2}}dx=\int\left(\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}}{1+x}+\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-x}\right)dx=\frac{1}{2}\ln|1+x|-\frac{1}{2}\ln|1-x|+C$$
On the other hand, from FTC 2 we know $$\int f(x)dx=\frac{-1}{1-x^2}+c\implies\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\left(\frac{-1}{1-x^2}+c\right)=f(x)$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited the question